Unable to install PimcoreDataHub on Ubuntu 22.04
I've been fighting trying to install Pimcore DataHub Bundle in my Ubuntu.
Following the installation guide I get this message

In Kernel.php line 219:
Bundle "PimcoreDataHubBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the "registerBundles()" method of your "App\Kernel.php" file?


pimcore:bundle:install [-f|--fail-without-error] [--no-post-change-commands] [--no-assets-install] [--no-cache-clear] [--] 

I don't know what I'm doing wrong with this, but it is getting a little bit frustrating.
Can anyone give me a hint of what to do or something??
Thanks in advance.
I've followed this guide

Please do not post images of error messages; post the actual error message as plain text: type it out if you have to. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also do not post a screenshot of the guide you're using, post a link to it so others can refer to it - you've only posted part of the guide.
